# Как установить MS SQL Server 2019 на Ubuntu Server 20.04, когда apt-get выдаёт ошибку "E: Unable to locate package mssql-server"?

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, raspberry-pi

Я следовал инструкциям на [Краткое руководство. Установка SQL Server и создание базы данных в Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15),
но эта **sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server** команда выдаёт ошибку.

Ubuntu установлен на Raspberry PI 4 (64 bit): *Linux 5.4.0-1048-raspi #53-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 8 13:06:23 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux*

Comment: Ну а индексы кэша apt ты конечно же обновил?

Comment: @donRumata Нет не обновлял, а как это сделать?

Comment: `apt-get update`

Comment: `apt-get update` Эту команду я конечно использовал. `apt-cache search mssql-server` ничего не выдаёт после `apt-get update`

Comment: Значит или ты репозиторий неправильно добавил или майки убрали пакет для arm, но забыли об этом написать.

Comment: __/etc/apt/sources.list__ есть такая строка `deb [arch=arm64,amd64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019 focal main`

Comment: @yW0K5o - "команда выдаёт ошибку." - То что вы показали - это **не** текст ошибки. Это просто информация о системе. Какую ошибку выдаёт? Что вообще происходит после печати этих строк?

Comment: ну, в общем, и правильно выдаёт: зачем загрязнять систему содержимым каких-то левых репозиториев? @Sergey, см. в заголовке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Архитектура aarch64 не поддерживается, и у вас не получится установить mssql на вашу систему.

Системные требования для установки MSSQL: x64 Processor: AMD Opteron, AMD Athlon 64, Intel Xeon with Intel EM64T support, Intel Pentium IV with EM64T support

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver15